# Determine if series with power of n converges or diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Does $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^{10}}{3^n-2^n} $$
Converges or diverges?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Also what type of convergence tests are you aware of?

Comment: Apply the root test (or ratio) test.  As a rule, exponential functions grow much faster than polynomials.  And, the sum of two exponential grows at the rate of the one with the larger base.

Comment: You can generally the website SYMBOLAB (just google it) to calculate limits, convergence, integrals etc. They offer detailed explanations for their answers.

Comment: Well my intuition was that it converges. I actually cheated too and checked it on wolfram and I was right, but I have no idea how to get to it. I tried the root test but I get stuck with the denominator

Comment: Also symbolab is being funny, https://www.symbolab.com/solver/power-series-calculator/%5Csum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%20%5Cfrac%7Bn%5E%7B10%7D%7D%7B3%5E%7Bn%7D-2%5E%7Bn%7D%7D
How does it get from the last long expression to $1/3$?

Comment: take the rationtest to Show that our sum converges

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I tried. I get to a long expression that doesn't help me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one wishes to use the root test, then simply note that

$$\begin{align}
\sqrt[n]{\left|\frac{n^{10}}{3^n-2^n}\right|}&=\frac13 n^{10/n}(1-(2/3)^n)^{-1/n}\\\\
\end{align}$$

Since $\lim_{n\to \infty }(1-(2/3)^n)=1$, we see that $\lim_{n\to \infty}(1-(2/3)^n)^{-1/n}=1$.

And $\lim_{n\to \infty}n^{10/n}=1$ also.

Therefore, we have

$$ \limsup_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{\left|\frac{n^{10}}{3^n-2^n}\right|}=\frac13$$ and the series converges.

Comment: I cannot use $log$ yet or the integral test

Comment: This does not use the integral test.

Comment: How come $\lim_{n\to \infty}(1-(2/3)^n)^{1/n}=1$.? It has power of $1/n$, can I still apply the arithmetic rules I've learned here?

Comment: I'm asking because it seems dangerous as $\lim_{n\to \infty}(1+1/n)^n$ appears to be $1$ but it's actually $e$

Comment: Note that $1/n\to 0$ and $1-(2/3)^n \to 1$.  So we have a determinate (not an indeterminate) form $1^0=1$.

Comment: I get it. Thanks!

Comment: And to show that $n^{10/n}\to 1$ without appealing to logarithms, we proceed as follows.  First, it is apparent that $n^{10/n}>1$.  Let $x>0$ be defined as $x=n^{10/n}-1$.  Then, we have $n^{10}=(1+x)^n$.  Now use the binomial theorem with $n\ge 11$ to show that $x\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$.

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.